# Turbolinks: what is the Rails 4 way of showing progress for slow pages?

Tags: javascript, browser, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, throbber

This question might sound similar to [Rails turbolinks long request doesn't show page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310392/rails-turbolinks-long-request-doesnt-show-page-load).

I've recently started new Rails 4 application, which uses Turbolinks library by default - it is awesome: makes the application feel faster/snappier, however I do have some pages that are slower than others.

Unfortunately I can't find a good way to make a browser show the **default loading indicator** - just like it does when it loads "conventional" web pages. People recommend different JavaScript solutions, for example, https://github.com/caarlos0/turbolinks_transitions. Although some do look good, but "average internet user" is not used to seeing loading progress somewhere other than the default browser's loading indicator.

- How can I make Chrome show that "spinning semi-circle" in the tab header?
- Or how can I make Safari show that "moving blue wave" in the address bar?
- Etc.

Most of my pages are fast though, so I'd like to show this loading indicator for the pages that won't load within 300 ms, for example.

Thank you!
Alex.

Comment: Here is what I do: https://gist.github.com/cpuguy83/5016442

Comment: That's a great answer and worked fine for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18815206/101900

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this isn't exactly what you want, you can change the cursor to be the loading cursor using javascript like this.

```
$('selector').css( 'cursor', 'wait' );
```

It would definitely let users know that a page is loading.  You can set/remove it with more javascript

Comment: That's a great and yet very simple idea - thank you, TMP! This would probably eliminate 1/2 of my users confusion. Sorry, not marking your answer as "accepted", because the question about how to make Chrome/Firefox/IE show page loading indicator remains open. Maybe I should talk to browser makers about that... :)